# Valgrind strange "Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)"

Tags: c, valgrind

Maybe I am completely blind or stupid but I do not understand how I am getting a valgrind problem here. Valgrind is giving me this:

```
==3728== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3728==    at 0x57835DC: send (send.c:33)
==3728==    by 0x4058B7: CBSocketSend (CBLibEventSockets.c:287)
==3728==    by 0x4E522FB: CBNetworkCommunicatorOnCanSend (CBNetworkCommunicator.c:649)
==3728==    by 0x40564F: CBCanSend (CBLibEventSockets.c:235)
==3728==    by 0x526E54B: event_base_loop (event.c:1346)
==3728==    by 0x405244: CBStartEventLoop (CBLibEventSockets.c:154)
==3728==    by 0x5A54E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==3728==  Address 0x5e7b6b4 is 20 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==3728==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3728==    by 0x4E51E2A: CBNetworkCommunicatorOnCanSend (CBNetworkCommunicator.c:592)
==3728==    by 0x40564F: CBCanSend (CBLibEventSockets.c:235)
==3728==    by 0x526E54B: event_base_loop (event.c:1346)
==3728==    by 0x405244: CBStartEventLoop (CBLibEventSockets.c:154)
==3728==    by 0x5A54E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==3728==
==3728== (action on error) vgdb me ...
```

When this happens GDB gives the backtrace:

```
0x00000000057835dc in __libc_send (fd=<optimized out>, buf=<optimized out>,
    n=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c:33
33  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000057835dc in __libc_send (fd=<optimized out>, buf=<optimized out>,
    n=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c:33
#1  0x00000000004058b8 in CBSocketSend (socketID=20,
    data=0x5e7b6a0 "\371\276\264\331version", len=24)
    at /media/sf_BitEagle_Projects/cbitcoin/dependencies/sockets/CBLibEventSockets.c:287
#2  0x0000000004e522fc in CBNetworkCommunicatorOnCanSend (vself=0x5e76c30, vpeer=0x5e791c0)
    at /media/sf_BitEagle_Projects/cbitcoin/src/structures/CBObject/CBNetworkCommunicator/CBNetworkCommunicator.c:649
#3  0x0000000000405650 in CBCanSend (socketID=20, eventNum=4, arg=0x5e7a2d0)
    at /media/sf_BitEagle_Projects/cbitcoin/dependencies/sockets/CBLibEventSockets.c:235
#4  0x000000000526e54c in event_process_active_single_queue (activeq=0x5e78be0,
    base=0x5e78710) at event.c:1346
#5  event_process_active (base=<optimized out>) at event.c:1416
#6  event_base_loop (base=0x5e78710, flags=0) at event.c:1617
#7  0x0000000000405245 in CBStartEventLoop (vloop=0x5e78eb0)
    at /media/sf_BitEagle_Projects/cbitcoin/dependencies/sockets/CBLibEventSockets.c:154
#8  0x0000000005a54e9a in start_thread (arg=0x7a74700) at pthread_create.c:308
#9  0x00000000057824bd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#10 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

So it can be seen here that the code is sending some allocated data with 24 bytes to send() which is what happens in CBSocketSend and then valgrind complains at sendto at 20 bytes into the data.

I fill in the data with this code:

```
peer->sendingHeader = malloc(24);
if (NOT peer->sendingHeader) {
    CBNetworkCommunicatorDisconnect(self, peer, 0, false);
    return;
}
peer->sendingHeader[0] = self->networkID;
peer->sendingHeader[1] = self->networkID >> 8;
peer->sendingHeader[2] = self->networkID >> 16;
peer->sendingHeader[3] = self->networkID >> 24;
// Get the message we are sending.
CBMessage * toSend = peer->sendQueue[peer->sendQueueFront];
// Message type text
if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_VERSION)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "version\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_VERACK)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "verack\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_ADDR)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "addr\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_INV)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "inv\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_GETDATA)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "getdata\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_GETBLOCKS)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "getblocks\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_GETHEADERS)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "getheaders\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_TX)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "tx\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_BLOCK)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "block\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_HEADERS)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "headers\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_GETADDR)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "getaddr\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_PING)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "ping\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_PONG)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "pong\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_ALERT)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, "alert\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 12);
else if (toSend->type == CB_MESSAGE_TYPE_ALT)
    memcpy(peer->sendingHeader + 4, toSend->altText, 12);
// Length
if (toSend->bytes){
    peer->sendingHeader[16] = toSend->bytes->length;
    peer->sendingHeader[17] = toSend->bytes->length << 8;
    peer->sendingHeader[18] = toSend->bytes->length << 16;
    peer->sendingHeader[19] = toSend->bytes->length << 24;
}else{
    memset(peer->sendingHeader + 16, 0, 4);
}
// Checksum
peer->sendingHeader[20] = toSend->checksum[0];
peer->sendingHeader[21] = toSend->checksum[1];
peer->sendingHeader[22] = toSend->checksum[2];
peer->sendingHeader[23] = toSend->checksum[3];
```

You can see quite clearly there that all of the data is assigned, right? So what is valgrind doing?

You can see the full function apparently causing troubles here: https://github.com/MatthewLM/cbitcoin/blob/master/src/structures/CBObject/CBNetworkCommunicator/CBNetworkCommunicator.c#L582

CBSocketSend is this:

```
int32_t CBSocketSend(uint64_t socketID,uint8_t * data,uint32_t len){
    ssize_t res = send((evutil_socket_t)socketID, data, len, CB_SEND_FLAGS);
    if (res >= 0)
        return (int32_t)res;
    if (errno == EAGAIN)
        return 0; // False event. Wait again.
    return CB_SOCKET_FAILURE; // Failure
}
```

Which is here: https://github.com/MatthewLM/cbitcoin/blob/master/dependencies/sockets/CBLibEventSockets.c#L286

Thank you.

Comment: I think in `peer->sendingHeader[17] = toSend->bytes->length << 8;` and the following two lines, you really want `>>` rather than `<<`. No idea whether that's relevant for the valgrind diagnosis.

Comment: `int8_t len = CBSocketSend(peer->socketID, ...)` is not wrong but it is at least supect; the other return types (ssize_t ...) are 32 bit types. Besides: I don't like the NOT, and I don't like the long "chained else if"s. @DanielFischer has a good catch.

Comment: @wildplasser: I don't know what I didn't use a switch statement. I'll change that. Also the "NOT" makes programming much easier for me since my eyes often pass "!". I used an 8 bit integer since that is all which is needed in this case but is it somehow better to use the return type of CBSocketSend?

Comment: 8-bit integers can be costlyer than native ints. And more error-prone, IMHO. wrt NOT: I beg to differ. You still have to read code from others who just use `if ( !*cp ) {}`.

Comment: There is no default handling for `peer->sendingHeader`'s bytes 4 to 15 in case `toSend->type` does not match any `CB_MESSAGE*`.

Comment: Are you sure `toSend->checksum` had been initialized?

Comment: Are the to loggings above from the same run or at least used the same builds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following Valgrind argument might help to determine where the uninitialised data comes from:

```
--track-origins=yes
```

You might also try using

```
 --vgdb-error=0
```

Put breakpoints before and after you initialise the byte 20, and verify what is happening using **memcheck** command **get_vbits**.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've not yet been able to debug everything properly yet. It can be quite tedious when things don't always want to work but I'll come back with details. I can say that --track-origins=yes tells me that the origin of the uninitialised data is apparently allocated on line 30 (https://github.com/MatthewLM/cbitcoin/blob/master/src/structures/CBObject/CBNetworkCommunicator/CBNetworkCommunicator.c#L30). That makes no sense to me. Hopefully I'll be able to figure it out tomorrow.

Comment: Valgrind is broken: Here is thinks the hash data is not being assigned but it is. I've verified this: https://github.com/MatthewLM/cbitcoin/blob/master/src/structures/CBObject/CBNetworkCommunicator/CBNetworkCommunicator.c#L1214 So all along valgrind was broken!!!

Comment: @MatthewMitchell: I used valgrind on lots of code, and doubt that valgrind is broken in this case. Looking at the code doing the hash's initialisation I see at least one possibility for the hash *not* being initialised properly. That is if `message->bytes->length` equals `0`. My well-meant advice: Consider doing more default intialisations and more error checking.

Comment: message->bytes->length doesn't equal 0. I checked.

Comment: So clearly valgrind is not picking up OpenSSL assigning to the data.

Comment: message->bytes->length should never equal 0. If that ever occurs, that is an error. I'll put an assert() call for that to check that it never occurs.

Comment: Well, I did find a case where I stupidly give a length of 0 but that was for something different...